# AlamoFire + ObjectMapper, how to have a function take a parameter of something that is of type Mappable?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I currently have a function:

```
  func getJSONDataDictionary (accessToken: String, response: Mappable, url: String) {

    let headers = [
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Authorization": "bearer \(accessToken)"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
      .responseObject{  (response: Response<response, NSError>) in

       let JSONDict = response.result.value

    }
  }
```

Where I want to pass in a class that is of type Mappable (which is class used to identify if a class conforms to the ObjectMapper protocol)  for the response parameter. With the code the way it is right now I get an error "response is not a type".  Is there something I can do to the function so it takes a Mappable parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that your parameter *result* is not a type, which it isn't. *Mappable* is a *protocol*.

I suggest you make your function generic, like so:

```
    func getJSONDataDictionary< T: Mappable>(accessToken: String, response: T, url: String) {

    let headers = [
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Authorization": "bearer \(accessToken)"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
      .responseObject{  (response: Response<response, NSError>) in

       let JSONDict = response.result.value

    }
  }
```

The generic type *T* will be constrained to the *Mappable* protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let pjson = attendences.toJSONString(prettyPrint: false)
    let data = (pjson?.data(using: .utf8))! as Data

    request.httpBody = data

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in


        print(response)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let query_url = Constant.BASE_URL + Constant.ENDPOINT
      var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: query_url)!)

      urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue
      urlRequest.addValue("Cache-Control", forHTTPHeaderField: "no-cache"")

      urlRequest.addValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField:"bearer \(accessToken)")

      let req = Alamofire.request(urlRequest)
      req.responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Model>) in
                let value = response.result.value
                print(value?.data?.count)  
            }
```